# boost::apply_visitor and lvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++14, boost-variant

Is it safe (I wonder about lifetime of `x`):

```
boost::apply_visitor([this](const auto& arg) { someClass.method(arg); }, x);
```

`apply_visitor` takes lvalue reference (non-const) but lambda has `const auto&` so is it safe?

Comment: I don't understand, increasing constness is never a problem and why should the lifetime of x be an issue? `apply_visitor` is a normal synchronous function call.

Comment: Please add the definition of your  `x` i.e. please post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)